# Return updated row attributes on UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-returning

My query is as follow:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.foreign_key = (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE t2.col = %s ) 
WHERE t1.col = %s
```

How do I return some attributes of the updated row in the table in the same query?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Use the **`RETURNING`** clause.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

> The optional `RETURNING` clause causes `UPDATE` to compute and return
> value(s) based on each row actually updated. Any expression using the
> table's columns, and/or columns of other tables mentioned in `FROM`, can
> be computed. The new (post-update) values of the table's columns are used.

Typically, it's smarter to use a join instead of a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET    foreign_key = t2.id
FROM   t2
WHERE  t2.col = %s
AND    t1.col = %s
RETURNING t1.*;   -- or only selected columns
```

With your original query, if the subquery finds no row in `t2`, `t1` is updated anyway and `t1.col` is set to null. Typically, you'd rather *not* update the row in this case, which is what my query does instead.

BTW, target columns in the `SET` clause cannot be table-qualified (only *one* table is updated anyway). The manual once more:

> Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target
> column — for example, `UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1` is invalid.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `RETURNING` clause:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.foreign_key = (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE t2.col = %s ) 
    WHERE t1.col = %s
    RETURNING *;
```

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html) is part of the `UPDATE` statement.