# Auto Increment column on SELECT Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

MySql 8

I have this `table`:

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 3 |
| 2 | name2 | 4 |

I'm looking for a way to increment `count` each time I get the count value.

Something like:

```sql
SELECT count FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND /*increase count value*/;
```

So this request will return: `3`

Then if I do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table;
```

I got:

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 4 |
| 2 | name2 | 4 |

I'm assuming I have to use an [Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) but I can't figure out how.

Thank you

Comment: This is not possible by the query - SELECT query does not produce any event itself. You may create SP for both UPDATE and SELECT.

Comment: Are you trying to keep track of how many times you've used a certain piece of data?

Comment: do you mean increment the count in your results or increment the count in your table?  if the latter, you would use a stored procedure for this, to increment the count and return the row's data

Comment: @ysth, I mean increment the count in the table as shown on my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xammax's answer didn't suit my need, I change my database from mysql to postgre and use this answer: [Return updated row attributes on UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948800/return-updated-row-attributes-on-update#answer-38948920)

Comment: You answered your own question. Glad you found an answer.